# iphone sdk - TableView Cell with custom TextView - Get New Data

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitableview, editing, textfield

I have a tableview cell with a custom textview in it, I am now left wondering how do I possibly access the text in the textbox after text has been edited/added.

I would normally know how this is done when I draw the textfield through IB, but my textviewcell is dynamically drawn.

**(i.e. I would like to capture the data that is updated in detailLabel.text)**

Here is the related code to adapt to your answer.
Thanks again!

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    //Big Text Box
    UITextView *detailLabel = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 80, 500, 150)];
    detailLabel.tag = 20;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
    detailLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    detailLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.9] CGColor];
    detailLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    detailLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
    [detailLabel release];

} 

UITextView * detailLabel = (UITextView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];

switch (indexPath.row) {

case 0:
    detailLabel.text = @"no";
    break;
default:
    detailLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    detailLabel.hidden = NO;    

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to listen for messages sent by the UITextView.  So look to implement the [UITextViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidEndEditing:) protocol and register the implementing class with the detailLabel using its [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/delegate) property.

When your delegate is notified of a change in the UITextView you'll have to identify the cell which currently owns the UITextView.  In doing so you must remember that cells can be reused.

I would start by looking at the following method in the UITableView class:

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells
```

We know that if the user has made a change to the UITextView's contents it must currently be on screen and therefore be present in the pre-mentioned array.  To find it we use the pointer to the UITextView which changed (it's a parameter in the textViewDidChange protocol method).  So simply iterate over the visibleCells array and retrieve the UITextView and compare it against the UITextView which changed.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
....
cellsLabel = (UITextView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
if (cellsLabel == textView)
...
```

You'll now have a handle to a cell in the UITableView.  To find the index use the following UITableView method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
```

Comment: Ah, i See ;)
First was the <UITextViewDelegate> trick in the .h and then the new method available is -(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView

Comment: OK, so now I can access the text in the text field, but how do I know which textbox is sending this information.
Lets say I have 15 cells, each with a textbox with different data.
Rgds.

Comment: Edited original answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks matt, I have this and a couple other related problems all resolved! Tonight I will sleep well. Thank you so much.